# Pulling out potentially overlapping subsets of elements in array to make smaller arrays

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, loops, sequence

My input file looks like below (real one is much larger):

```
rs3683945_mark  0
rs6336442_mark  1E-07
rs31328150_impute   0.444121193
rs3658242_mark  0.444121293
rs39342374_impute   0.444121393
IMP!1!  1
rs3677817_mark  1.986015679
IMP!2!  2
SNP117_impute   2.685815665
IMP!3!  3
SNP3_1_impute   3.643119709
SNP1_impute 3.643119809
rs13475706_mark 3.643119909
```

13 lines, two elements each line.  First element is a name.  Each name ends either with a "tag" `_mark` or `impute`, or there is no tag.  The point of the tag is to distinguish between types of names, which form the basis of my search for subsets within the entire list.

The subsets *begin* with a `_mark` name that immediately *precedes* an instance of an `_impute` name. The subsets *end* with the very next instance of `_mark`.  All names in between, which will necessarily not have any such tag, also go into a subset, which I'd like to collect into an array and send off to a subroutine to process (details of that not important). Please note, the positions with `IMP` in the name are not the same as those actually tagged with a `_impute`.

For example, with the above, the first useable subset is:

```
rs6336442_mark  1E-07
rs31328150_impute   0.444121193
rs3658242_mark  0.444121293
```

The second useable subset is:

```
rs3658242_mark  0.444121293
rs39342374_impute   0.444121393
IMP!1!  1
rs3677817_mark  1.986015679
```

and so on... EDIT:  Note that last `_mark` name of the first set is the first `_mark` name of the second.

My code for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;                                         


my $usage = "usage: merge_impute.pl {genotype file} {distances file} \n";
die $usage unless @ARGV == 2;


my $genotypes = $ARGV[0];               
     open (FILE, "<$genotypes");               
my @genotypes = <FILE>;                      
     close FILE;

my $distances = $ARGV[1];       
     open (DISTS, "<$distances");
my @distances = <DISTS>;
     close DISTS; 

my @workingset = ();

#print scalar @distances;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @distances; $i++ ){
      chomp $distances[$i];
      #print "$distances[$i]\n";
      if ( $distances[$i] =~ m/impute/ ){
           push ( @workingset,$distances[$i-1],$distances[$i],$distances[$i+1]); 
      }
      print "i=$i: @workingset\n";
      # at this point send off to sub routine
      @workingset=();
}
```

As you can see, the `if` loop is only set up to find subsets that contain only one `_impute` name.  How can I modify the code so that a subset will "fill up" with as many names as required until we arrive at the next `_mark` name?

EDIT:  Perhaps instead of the `for` loop, I could something like...

```
push (@workingset, $distances[0], $distances[1] );
until ( $distance[ ??? ] =~ m/_mark/ ){
        push ( @workingset, $distance[ ??? ] );
}
```

But what could `$distances[ ??? ]` be?

EDIT: Or an alternative `for` loop...

```
push (@workingset, $distances[0] );
for ( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @distances - 1 ; $i++ ){
      until ( $distances[ $i ] =~ m/_mark/ ){
      push  ( @workingset, $distances[ $i ] );
      # send @workingset to sub routine
      #clear workingset
      @workingset = ();
     }

}
```

Though this isn't working.

I also tried...

```
push (@workingset, $distances[0] );
for ( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @distances - 1 ; $i++ ){
      until ( $distances[ $i ] =~ m/_mark/ ){
              push  ( @workingset, $distances[ $i ] );
              next if $distances[ $i+1 ] !~ /_mark/;
      }
      # send @workingset to sub routine here
      print "i=$i, @workingset\n\n";
      #clear workingset
      @workingset = ();

}
```

Comment: Something like `next if $distance[$i] =~ /_mark/` might work at the beginning of the `for` loop? Do you need to do anything with lines that match `_mark` or can you just skip it?

Comment: If I understand you correctly...some or many of the `_mark` names will be used twice.  First as the end of a subset, then again as the beginning of the next subset.

Comment: But if the next element is not matching `_mark`, then I am still stuck.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `IMP` lines? I think I see what is going on now, my previous comment didn't really make sense.

Comment: The `Imp` lines just go into the subsets when they are in between two flanking `_mark` positions. They will get attention once a subset has been made and sent to a subroutine, which I am not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of time right now but I'll hopefully have some time in the morning to check back. Here's a quick example on how you could do it (it is meant to be simple and easy to understand, not fancy). Hopefully it helps you get on the right track for parsing the data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $first_mark;
my @workingset = ();
my $second_mark;

while (<DATA>){
    chomp;
    if ( /_mark/ and scalar @workingset == 0 ) {
        $first_mark = $_;
    } elsif ( /IMP|_impute/ and defined $first_mark) {
        push @workingset, $_;
    } elsif ( /_mark/ and defined $first_mark) {
        $second_mark = $_;
        print "Found valid set: ";
        print "$first_mark," . join(",", @workingset) . ",$second_mark\n";

        @workingset = ();
        $first_mark = $second_mark;
        undef $second_mark;
    }
}



__DATA__
rs3683945_mark  0
rs6336442_mark  1E-07
rs31328150_impute   0.444121193
rs3658242_mark  0.444121293
rs39342374_impute   0.444121393
IMP!1!  1
rs3677817_mark  1.986015679
IMP!2!  2
SNP117_impute   2.685815665
IMP!3!  3
SNP3_1_impute   3.643119709
SNP1_impute 3.643119809
rs13475706_mark 3.643119909
```

Output:

```
Found valid set: rs6336442_mark  1E-07,rs31328150_impute   0.444121193,rs3658242_mark  0.444121293
Found valid set: rs3658242_mark  0.444121293,rs39342374_impute   0.444121393,IMP!1!  1,rs3677817_mark  1.986015679
Found valid set: rs3677817_mark  1.986015679,IMP!2!  2,SNP117_impute   2.685815665,IMP!3!  3,SNP3_1_impute   3.643119709,SNP1_impute 3.643119809,rs13475706_mark 3.643119909
```